# Node server receiving file upload as String: '[object ArrayBuffer]'

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I'm trying to upload a file to my node server. Here's my client-side code:

```
// data is {_id: 'somebigstring', file: an ArrayBuffer}

api.addDocument = function (data, cb){
    // $.post(BASE_PATH + '/requests/addDocument', data, cb);
    var formData = new FormData();

    _.keys(data).forEach(key => {
        formData.append(key, data[key]);
    })

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: BASE_PATH + '/requests/addDocument',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    }).done(cb);
}
```

Here's what I'm doing server-side (in Node and Express):

```
app.use(multer({dest:'./uploads/'}));
app.use(function (req, res, next){
    debugger;
    next();
});
```

At the `debugger` line, I check `req.body` and get this:

```
{ _id: '555bcc06798e6f9c69b461e0',
  file: '[object ArrayBuffer]' }
```

How do I get the actual file, rather than `'[object ArrayBuffer]'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`form.append()` only supports values that are one of: string, File, or Blob. If the value is not one of those, it is converted to a string (this is why you see the result of `.toString()` as the value for your `file`).

So one solution might be to instead do:

```
_.keys(data).forEach(key => {
  var val = data[key];
  if (val instanceof ArrayBuffer)
    val = new Blob([val]);
  formData.append(key, val);
})
```

Comment: I took out the FileReader and just sent the File object across - seems to be working great. Thank you, this was a huge pain today. :)